# Python Percent from List of Numbers

Tags: python, if-statement

Given a list of integers age = [14, 19, 20, 15, 16, 40, 39], I need to determine which percentage of people are not in high school (High school: Age 14-18). I created if conditions to determine whether the people are in high school, but I don't know how to determine the % of people not in high school after.

```
age = [14, 19, 20, 15, 16, 40, 39]

for i in age:
    if (i>=14 and i<=18):
        print("In high school")
    else:
        print("Not in high school")
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: "percentage of" is   "the number of people in high school" / "total number of people" * 100

Comment: Think about the problem. You want the number of people in high school. As you loop through the list, how would you count this number?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply sum up the generator function to get the count of people in high school.

```py
age = [14, 19, 20, 15, 16, 40, 39]
count = sum(1 for i in age if 14 <= i <= 18)
percent = (count/len(age))*100
```

Comment: @PranavHosangadi good point, fixed

Answer (score -1):

I would start by counting the number of people you find who are in high school and then dividing by the total amount of people.

```
( Num people in high school / Num total people ) * 100 = % of people in high school.
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Generator expression like this:

```
import math

age = [14, 19, 20, 15, 16, 40, 39]

percent = math.floor(sum(1 for i in age if i >= 14 and i <= 18)/len(age) * 100)
print(percent) # 42
```

Comment: Why do you need to floor? How is your answer different from Abhinav's?

Comment: Code snippets are for html/js/css. Please use code blocks for other languages.